# WHERE Query Scenario

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table in DB with various columns, one of them being `Name`. Suppose the `Name`s in DB are A,B,C,D,E,F.

I wrote a query:

```
Select * from Table where Name IN (#ENTERED_NAMES#)
```

(Suppose `#ENTERED_NAMES#` are the various names entered by USER on GUI)

Now suppose that the user enters in the GUI the following names: A,B,C,Y,Z

Since A,B,C are valid names but Y,Z is not present in DB,
so I want the results of A,B,C as it is, but for Y,Z(invalid  values) I want results of name "D" for all invalid values.

So the query should come as

```
Select * from Table where Name IN (A,B,C,D)
```

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: yes unique, i am using DB2

Comment: Is there something to distinguish 'D' as the name for invalid values as opposed to 'E', 'F', or any other?

Answer (score 2):

try this
first concat  the string as 'A','B','C'

```
Select * from Table where Name IN ('A','B','C');
```

Comment: you should have inverted comma seperated string because name are in the form of string

Comment: You did not get my question

Comment: Ya i failed to write inverted commas in my question, ignore that

Comment: can you give some idea what names you called valid

Comment: Valid names are those that are present in DB, invalid are those that are not present in DB. My question is the same, How to check for invalid names?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
-- create a table containing all valid names
create table valid_names (name varchar(20));
insert into valid_names values ('A');
insert into valid_names values ('B');
insert into valid_names values ('C');
commit;

with usernames (name) as (
   values ('A'),('B'),('C'),('X'),('Y') -- this is the user input
)
select case
         when vn.name is null then 'D'
         else un.name
       end as name,
       case
         when vn.name is null then 'invalid'
         else 'valid'
       end as name_info -- name info is just for the demo!
from usernames un
 left join valid_names vn on vn.name = un.name;
```

returns the following:

```
NAME | NAME_INFO
-----+----------
A    | valid    
B    | valid    
C    | valid    
D    | invalid  
D    | invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you should really want, but it seems to be what you asked for:

If you have a temporary table where you insert your GUI input values, then

```
SELECT coalesce(t.name,'D') 
    FROM gui_input g
    LEFT JOIN db_table t  on g.name = t.name
```

You would be a bit better off with this:

```
SELECT g.name, coalesce(t.name,'*invalid*')
    FROM gui_input g
    LEFT JOIN db_table t  on g.name = t.name
```

or

```
SELECT g.name, case when t.name is null then '*OK*' else '*invalid*' end
    FROM gui_input g
    LEFT JOIN db_table t  on g.name = t.name
```

But still, I'm not sure we have quite the right question for what will best suit whatever you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing you can do is to write a "CASE" for all the input values other than the values present in database.